# Conditional Probability/Terminology Question

Tags: probability, random-variables, terminology

I have two events $X,Y$ and a family of events $\lbrace E_i\rbrace$.  I want to consider the following condition:

> The value of the expression $$\mathsf P(X\mid E_i)\,\mathsf P(Y\mid E_i)\over \mathsf P(X \cap Y\mid E_i)$$
> is independent of $i$.

Is there a name for this condition, or do I need to invent one?

Comment: Clarrification: are you using $\wedge$ as 'conjunction' or 'minimum'?

Comment: @GrahamKemp :  Wedge means conjunction.   Will edit to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the conditional covariance of two events when given a third is : $$\mathsf {Cov}(X,Y\mid E_i) ~=~ {\mathsf P(X\cap Y\mid E_i)- \mathsf P(X\mid E_i)\,\mathsf P(Y\mid E_i)}$$

So $\dfrac{ \mathsf P(X\mid E_i)\,\mathsf P(Y\mid E_i) }{ \mathsf P(X\cap Y\mid E_i)} ~=~ 1- \dfrac{\mathsf {Cov}(X,Y\mid E_i)}{\mathsf P(X\cap Y\mid E_i)}$

Which ... I don't think has any particular meaning.

Comment: Thanks.  I agree that this is probably the best one can do.  I've just posted a closely related question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2392408/another-conditional-probability-terminology-question .